# Branch Cut of $\log{\log{z}}$

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm wondering if I could get tips on how to get a definition of a branch of $\log \log z$, and how to prove that this branch is analytic.

As I understand it, the usual definition of the principal branch for $\log z$ excludes the negative real axis and $z$ s.t. $|\mathrm{Im}\log z| < \pi$. I'm not sure how to come up with a comparable principal branch for $\log \log z$, though?

Any help would definitely be appreciated!

Comment: If you use the principal branch, you could further exclude all $z$ such that $\log z$ is real and $\leqslant 0$.

Comment: What is the motivation for choosing that as the branch? Apologies if this would be obvious to those with a deeper understanding of this subject than me, but I'm not sure why we can then show that such a branch is analytic.

Comment: You know that the principal branch of the logarithm is analytic on $G := \mathbb{C}\setminus (-\infty,0]$, I presume. Then you can choose $U = \log^{-1}(G)$ as the domain of $\log \log z$. As a composition of analytic functions, that is analytic. You can choose other branches that are analytic on other domains. For example, if $\log_k$ denotes the branch of the logarithm on $G$ with $(2k-1)\pi < \operatorname{Im}\log_k z < (2k+1)\pi$, then $\log_0\circ \log 1$ is a branch of $\log \log z$ on $G$.